# "If I knew something about [X], I couldn't tell you what it is!"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Someone has told me that, because I asked about X. I know that the person has confidentiality concerns about the X-related issues. Now I'm wondering: does that statement imply anything specific? Something like "I know something about X, but I can't tell you what it is"?

PS: the guy is a native English speaker.

Apologies if wrong tagging..

Comment: I would interpret this as meaning that someone may know something of X-related issues, but the  knowledge is so minimal or so deeply buried within other information that it's not available to consciousness. There may be a gut feeling it's there, but it can't be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is implied except that the topic is confidential or secret. Starting the answer 'If I knew something about X...' is a way of saying 'I am not even telling you whether I know anything about X'.